global pageTransition hooks not working - Nuxt 3
I want to run pageTransition hooks for each page of the nuxt.config.ts file, but the hooks do not work!!
Pages :
/test :
<script setup lang="ts"></script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/test2">test2</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

/test2 :
<script setup lang="ts"></script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test 2 Page</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/test">test</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>



nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  nitro: {
    static: true,
  },
  app: {
    pageTransition: {
      name: "page",
      mode: "in-out",
      onEnter(el, done) {
        console.log("enter");
        done();
      },
      onLeave(el, done) {
        console.log("leave");
        done();
      },
    },
  },
});


onEnter and onLeave do not work.
It also does not work in layouts. I want it to work on certain pages, not all pages.

Can you try the transitions with CSS rather than JS? .page-enter-active, .page-leave-active etc...

The global page transition can be achieved by the usage of CSS that will be applied to each of pages with a CSS selector, this is both performant and the meant usage for CSS.
You could set some global values as shown here
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    pageTransition: {
      name: 'fade',
      mode: 'out-in' // default
    },
    layoutTransition: {
      name: 'slide',
      mode: 'out-in' // default
    }
  }
})

But you still need to write a global CSS file the definition of this animation somewhere.
Easiest approach is to use what's written in the app.vue to have something global.
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<style>
.layout-enter-active,
.layout-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.layout-enter-from,
.layout-leave-to {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
</style>

The JavaScript hooks are not meant to be global because they would require the usage of some querySelectors. This will not be proper usage of JS here due to the state nature of Vue/Nuxt.
You can meanwhile use them for logging, triggering specific actions etc...
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  pageTransition: {
    name: 'custom-flip',
    mode: 'out-in',
    onBeforeEnter: (el) => {
      console.log('Before enter...')
    },
    onEnter: (el, done) => {},
    onAfterEnter: (el) => {}
  }
})
</script>

But those are NOT meant for transition in this context. A VueJS app might be fine-ish, but why would you use JS for transitions in an isomorphic environment with hydration happening? It's just asking for pain.
Of course, if you use GSAP or something else, then it makes sense to do so but it will be a page-per-page basis or a layout transition on the upper level with a global initialization. Which I think is not what you're asking for in this question, would have mentioned it otherwise.

Actually, I have more than one page, all of them are in the same layout, and the only thing that changes is the content. I wanted to run it in the layout, meaning when I move from one page to the page of the same layout, the animation becomes when I move with the content.

https://codefile.io/f/c1fYHkXT9V

I can't use pageTransition in layout, The idea here: https://suar.me/oq4e1

If we assume the name of this layout, for example, “controlPanel”, I need to run middleware or pageTransition, for example, for all pages belonging to this layout, so I use definePageMeta inside the layout. Is this also correct? How do I implement the idea? I applied it using layout and pages
